# Cannot read data into colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I've mounted my Google Drive folder using code

```
from google.colab import drive                   
drive.mount("gdrive", force_remount=True)
```

as my data files are all under `gdrive/My Drive`.

Then I want to concat all the files ended with `"_1m."` using code

```
import os
import glob
path ='/gdrive'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*_1m.*")
df_tmv_report = pd.DataFrame()

for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_, sep=',')
    list_.append(df)
df_data = pd.concat(list_).iloc[:,1:].reset_index()
```

Colab returned

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-ec891ccb4282> in <module>()
----> 1 df_data = pd.concat(list_).iloc[:,1:].reset_index()

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, join_axes, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
    260 
    261         if len(objs) == 0:
--> 262             raise ValueError('No objects to concatenate')
    263 
    264         if keys is None:

ValueError: No objects to concatenate
```

I am not sure how to read the files correctly. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you executed `drive.mount("gdrive")`, your Drive files will be present in `/content/gdrive` rather than `/gdrive`. (The default working directory is `/content`.)

Try adjusting your path to `/content/gdrive`. You can use the file browser in the left hand panel to ensure your Drive is mounted where you expect.